# Bash - "/" is a directory

Tags: bash, alias

This is really confusing...

I currently have a Debian 8 computer, and I connect to it using PuTTY (SSH).
The default console used is Bash.

When I try to pass a path to an alias, it gives the following error:

```
 -bash: /: Is a directory
```

---

Here is an example:

[image: putty]

Also, there's a bizarre behaviour: running `'/'` or `"/"` cause the same error, as if Bash were ignoring quotes.

---

If it matters, the alias `explorer` was defined like this:

```
alias explorer='pcmanfm 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

---

Is this the expected behaviour?
If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Also, there's a bizarre behaviour: running '/' or "/" cause the same error, as if Bash were ignoring quotes._ - What are you expecting bash to do when you type `'/'`?

Comment: @marcelm A syntax error, a warning or just displaying `/` (similar to `echo`).

Comment: The syntax is fine so there is no syntax error, you **do** get a warning ("/: Is a directory"), and just displaying `/` would be inconsistent with anything else bash does. Try comparing the results of entering `'garply'`, `'ls'`, `'/bin/ls'`, `'/bin'` and `'/'`? Also try them without the quotes; why would the quotes change the result?

Comment: You might find this [explanation of **how quotes relate to argument lists**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13819996/5419599) helpful.  Particularly the last paragraph.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way you wrote your alias, the command you run would be expanded as

```
pcmanfm 1>/dev/null 2>&1 & '/'
```

This will run `pcmanfm` without any options as a background job and *then* try to run `/` as a command.

You probably want a function instead of an alias

```
explorer() { pcmanfm "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 & }
```

Comment: But `'/'` is in single quotes. Why would Bash even attempt to run it? (I understand if it was with `"/"`)

Comment: `'/foo/bar/baz'` will try and run the command; the quotes here don't matter.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the quotes are irrelevant. The point is that the `&` is a [list terminator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222) so bash reads the next item (whatever that may be) as a command.

Comment: @terdon So, if I do `echo 'a' & 'rm -rf /'`, it will nuke my system?

Comment: Thank you a lot for the function. I really tried a function before, but, I couldn't do it. I am accepting this answer since it is the first one and provides a fix.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel no, `'rm -rf /'` tries to run a command containing 8 characters. It's highly unlikely there is such a command so it will fail. On the other hand `'rm' '-rf' '/'` will succeed in running the `rm` command with an instruction to (attempt to) remove the entire filesystem.

Comment: @roaima That almost makes sense to me. But, that is an entirelly new question. Thank you a lot for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 4):

The alias provides a literal expansion. So running `explorer /` maps to

```
pcmanfm 1>/dev/null 2>&1 & /
```

This runs `pcmanfm` in the background, immediately followed by `/` in the foreground.

Comment: That addresses the `explorer /`, but not the quoted `/`. But it is still correct.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `'/'` is identical to `/`. What is there to explain?

Comment: That they are identical?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel why do you expect them to be different?

Comment: Is `'rm'` the same as `rm` or `"rm"`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes. The quotes don't make any difference here. Not when the word inside them is being treated as a command and the quotes don't protect a word from being treated as a command.

Comment: @terdon That begs the question: "What would protect a word from being treated as a command, besides comments?"

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel nothing, really, it depends on how it is presented to the shell. That does deserve it's own question though.